# React Send Data Between Indirect Childs/Parents

Tags: reactjs

I have the below Parent/Child set up. I set it up this way to make it more organized and easy, though now I start seeing why it's impossible to do some things without Redux.

Below is my component Set-up:
[image]

There's a search field in the Account Search so when user fills up I need to trigger an API call, which is no big deal. Then I get the data and make the data in the state equal to the data I pulled from through API.  `{ isLoaded: true, api: data.data }`

Then I have to send this data to the Daily component so it can display the data. It's significantly more over convoluting to send the value of the field within AccountSearch component to it's parent AppBarPanel then to his Parent Skeleton, then update the data state in Skeleton and send the data to Content then to it's child Router then to correct page which in this case Daily so data gets displayed.

How can I simplify my life here?

Below is the API Call I have

```
this.apiService
  .callApi("A", "B", "C")
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true, api: data.data });
    toastr.success('Api returned data successfully.');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    toastr.error(error);
  })
```

Comment: You don't need redux for this. Your app tree looks very small, have you considered storing the state at the `App` level? then you don't need to pass anything between siblings, you just pass down from parent

Comment: why would skeleton have any state? sounds like you're duplicating a lot of state for some reason

Comment: Well, how do I get the data? From a search within Account Search. So I need to read what user types inside the input field within this component, then send that value to AppBarPanel, then to Skeleton (which is the parent for both)..... Then this data gets updated and send that data to Content from that to Router from that to Daily. See so many components needs to be involved, I need to initilizate a lot of things to get this going

Comment: Skeleton is like the parent component for all components. It's like our body, holds everything in together. So I have all states there instead of App.js.

Comment: You don't pass it back up through every component... when App provides a function and state on props, you just pass props... then call the `props.whateveryourFunctionIs(data)`, you're not actually handling that in any of the intermediate components

Comment: So if I need to send GrandParent a data I don't need to tell first to the Parent?? Is there any example of skipping parent and communicating GrandParent and GrandChild?

Comment: yes there are lots of examples.. read this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and then read this https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Awesome I guess my options are either use Redux, OR use Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Thank you @azium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is all about data flowing down in the component's hierarchy, which means that horizontal data shouldn't happen, if you are facing a situation where you need to pass data horizontally I advice you to rethink your component's structure. There is a couple of things that you can try:

- Use redux ou similar to centralize your application's state
- Wrap your components on a parent component that distributes the data
- Use [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Well Redux is a great idea, I agree, but isn't there any other easier way to do this?

Comment: redux is just a state container... you still need to "connect" your components to that state. you can acheive the same thing with a simple stateful component and the context api

Comment: Just to get what user typed form 1 component to get data and deliver that I need to get 6 components involved OR use Redux ??

Comment: Yeah, if Redux is overkill to your project you can use a stateful component or Context API

Comment: so to reiterate.. you don't "involve" components by passing props down the tree. are you trying to access those props in each component inbetween? anyways using the context api is precisely what gets around passing props down through intermediate components, but its important to understand react well that passing props down is totally normal and not as complicated as you're making it seem

Comment: @Dupocas you have to use a stateful component *and* the context api, you can't just use the context api on its own to manage state

Comment: By involving, I meant, I need to accept at parent level and send that data to parent of that person. But, I don't know of a way to skip parent of a component and have GrandChild and GrandParent communicate directly

Comment: Agree, but i'm not advising him to use context for state manipulation, I'm advising to use context as a way to have access to other component's state instead of using redux

Comment: you never send data up through the tree.. you pass a function down and pass data through the function

Comment: I didn't mentioned on my answer but you can always use good old js events too.

Comment: Thank you @Dupocas

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there are many instances where you get horizontal requirements for data exchange between components in different branches of the tree (if not then redux would never have been invented).

There are many ways to achieve this:

1. **Redux** - what most people use but requires a lot of boilerplate and complexity.
2. **Context** - Facebook's built-in solution for what you want to do
3. **Events** - the native JavaScript way

You can use a library such as [pubsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) or native js events

e.g. in your receiving component:

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.addEventListener("dataArrived", this.handleData)
}
```

and in your other component:

```
// on data arrived
var event = new CustomEvent('dataArrived', { detail: mydata });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

4. **Use Globals** - Attach to global window (not recommended)

   getDataApi().then(data => window.data = data)

listening component:

```
setInterval(() => if (window.data) { this.setState(window.data) }, 1000);
```